# CSS img overflow my div

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have 3 div with height : 100vh
But with the responsive my imgs overflow. You can check that on the image. 
Sorry for my poor english !

This is the html :

```
<section id="services" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2>Services </h2>
                <ul> 
                    <li>Covoiturages </li>
                    <li>Food </li>
                    <li>Hébergement </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img src="img/mockup-iphone.png" alt="mockup iphone" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>

</section> <!-- close about -->
<section id="communities" class="container content-section text-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <img src="img/mockup-iphone.png" alt="mockup iphone" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2>Communities </h2>
                <ul> 
                    <li>Texte </li>
                    <li>Texte </li>
                    <li>Texte </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

And the css :

```
#services{
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: #62b030;
}
#services img{
    height:90%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we get some code or a live example?

Comment: E qual è Il problema?

Comment: You need to clearly show your code/effort, what have to tried to do so far, desired output and the problem you are facing. please edit your question

Comment: @SouravGhosh i have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Try to smaller the img to height: 80vh, or calc image max-height: calc(100vh-100px); overflow:hidden for #services might work, too. YOu can also add width, adn height to your img-responsive or your img class.